# nested listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, nested

i have list view and inside lisetview i have another list vie like nested listview
lv1 --> lv2 and inside lv2 i have button when i'll click buttion than insert template show  but how can fine control lv2 ....? there is my code
Lv1 is working but lv2 is creating problem..?

```
protected void lv1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "NewRecord")
    {

       lv1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;

    }
}

protected void lv2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "NewRecord")
    {
       //ListView lv2 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv2");
       //lv2.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can easily access your lv2 control by casting `sender` argument:

```
protected void lv2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "NewRecord")
    {
       ListView lv2 = (ListView)sender;
       lv2.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hey Hary i think i know very well waqa waqa!!
First of all ,are you sure that the second list view in the item template???
or is it in the select , edite Or insert template ???

if it's in the item template then :

to find the second list view you should use this code :
in vb.net:

```
dim Lv2 as listvew = lv.Item.FindControl("listview2")
```

in c# :

```
listvew Lv2 = lv.Item.FindControl("listview2");
```

then you have to find your button inside that lv2

```
button newbtn= lv2.Item.FindControl("UrBtnName");
```

then you can

see this is the code in vb.net

```
Sub buttons(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles LVCategories.ItemCommand
        Try
            Select Case e.CommandName

                Case "Delete"
                    'this to take a value from any control
                    Dim Idlabel As Label = e.Item.FindControl("CatIDLabel")
                    Session("ID") = Idlabel.Text()
                Case "new"
                    'Show the insert template
                    LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem
                Case "Cancel"
                    'Hide code
                    LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None

                Case "Edit"
                    'Hide code
                    LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None

                Case "Update"
                    Dim PictureIDlbl As Label = LVCategories.EditItem.FindControl("ImageIDLabel")
                    '
                    Dim fu As FileUpload = LVCategories.EditItem.FindControl("FileUpload")
                    If fu.HasFile Then

                        Dim PictureID As String = PictureIDlbl.Text()
                        Session("ImageID") = PictureID.ToString

                        Dim filepath As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ADMIN/ImageUpload/Categories/"), PictureID + ".jpg")
                        fu.SaveAs(filepath)
                    End If
                Case "Insert"
                    'Uploader Code
                    Dim fu As FileUpload = LVCategories.InsertItem.FindControl("FileUpload1")
                    Dim ad As New Images()
                    Dim dt As Images.ImagesDataTable
                    ad.DML("1", Nothing, "Categories", "Category Image")
                    dt = ad.Read("3", Nothing, Nothing)
                    Dim DR As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
                    Dim Imgid As String = DR.Item("ImageID")
                    Session("ImageID") = Imgid.ToString
                    If fu.HasFile Then
                        Dim filepath As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ADMIN/ImageUpload/Categories/"), Imgid + ".jpg")
                        fu.SaveAs(filepath)
                    End If
                    'Hiding the insert template
                    LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None
            End Select

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End Sub
```

and you can see this code in C#:

```
public void buttons(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
try {
    switch (e.CommandName) {

        case "Delete":
            //this to take a value from any control
            Label Idlabel = e.Item.FindControl("CatIDLabel");
            Session("ID") = Idlabel.Text();
            break;
        case "new":
            //Show the insert template
            LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
            break;
        case "Cancel":
            //Hide code
            LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;

            break;
        case "Edit":
            //Hide code
            LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;

            break;
        case "Update":
            Label PictureIDlbl = LVCategories.EditItem.FindControl("ImageIDLabel");
            //
            FileUpload fu = LVCategories.EditItem.FindControl("FileUpload");

            if (fu.HasFile) {
                string PictureID = PictureIDlbl.Text();
                Session("ImageID") = PictureID.ToString();

                string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ADMIN/ImageUpload/Categories/"), PictureID + ".jpg");
                fu.SaveAs(filepath);
            }
            break;
        case "Insert":
            //Uploader Code
            FileUpload fu = LVCategories.InsertItem.FindControl("FileUpload1");
            Images ad = new Images();
            Images.ImagesDataTable dt = default(Images.ImagesDataTable);
            ad.DML("1", null, "Categories", "Category Image");
            dt = ad.Read("3", null, null);
            DataRow DR = dt.Rows(0);
            string Imgid = DR["ImageID"];
            Session("ImageID") = Imgid.ToString();
            if (fu.HasFile) {
                string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ADMIN/ImageUpload/Categories/"), Imgid + ".jpg");
                fu.SaveAs(filepath);
            }
            //Hiding the insert template
            LVCategories.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;
            break;
    }


} catch (Exception ex) {
}
}
```

there are lots of example in this sample to know how to find a control in list view

thanks and good luck for you.